# EF Enumerable.Contains and query performance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

in my queries I often use Enumerable.Contains(..), and in complex queries actual query compilation takes forever (like 10-20s), while the query execution takes less than a second.

Does anyone have any advice (workaround) regarding this problem. I need to use Enumerable.Contains, since I have a table with hierarchical structure (n-level deep). If we take a well known example:

```
CPU
-- AMD
  -- FX
  -- A8
-- Intel
  -- I3
  -- I5
```

etc. If I need to retrieve data for all CPU's I first get the IDs of all products that belong to this group (and subgroups), and then use

```
ProductIds.Contains(p.Id)
```

in a query. This also prevents caching, so query is always being recompiled. If anyone knows a better way, my ears are open.

Regards,
Goran

Comment: 10-20 seconds to compile a query?!

Comment: Yes. And when I execute this compiled query directly into SSMS, then it takes less than a second. Query has lots of CASE sums, groupings, lots of JOINS....

Comment: What do you mean by "compile" here? I don't think you quite have that right.

Comment: OK, that's nothing to do with compilation then.

Comment: @DavidG When I execute L2Entities query, it takes approx 20s to execute and retrieve data of 100bytes size. If I use SQL profiler to get the query executed, and execute it as a raw SQL, then it takes only 1s. Did I get it right? :)

Comment: @DavidG What does it have to do with then, if not compilation? The code only executes query, nothing else. And EF needs first to compile it, and then execute it.

Comment: Please post your EF Context and entity relationships.

Comment: as the generated SQL for .Contains is rather long (IN(VALUES)), the compilation of the query could be a performance hit indeed. if you are sure this is the spot that marks the performance problems (and not context/connection initialization or materialization), you could try precompiling the queries by executing a dummy query beforehand - actual precompilation sadly got removed after EF4.

Comment: Query cannot be compiled when using IEnumerable.Contains, this is my biggest issue here. Context generation is quite fast, and this is never the first query to execute. I cannot show complete model, but there is about 30 entities, mostly 1-many relationships.